# GCKSessionManager - session not being resumed

Tags: ios, sdk, chromecast

I have created an IOS Sender application (for a chromecast custom receiver application). The sender application uses GCKUICastButton to handle the creation of the connection between the sender and the receiver.

I have set the option:

```
let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: 
GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: kReceiverAppID))
options.physicalVolumeButtonsWillControlDeviceVolume = true
options.suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded = false
options.disableDiscoveryAutostart = false
options.stopReceiverApplicationWhenEndingSession = true
GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
```

But if the sender application is sent to background (eg. press the Home Screen) or if I 'Lock' the phone, then the sender application loses the connection and it's not resumed when the application becomes active again (the receiver application is stil running). An instance of the session manager still exists, but not active CastSession is available, furthermore the Icon for GCKUICastButton is marked as 'No Connected'

According to the documentation the GCKSessionManager should handle this automatically:
"GCKSessionManager handles the automatic resumption of suspended sessions (that is, resuming sessions that were ended when the application went to the background, or in the event that the application crashed or was forcibly terminated by the user). When the application resumes or restarts, the session manager will wait for a short time for the device provider of the suspended session's device to discover that device again, and if it does, it will attempt to reconnect to that device and re-establish the session automatically."

I am using SDK 4.4.5